# How to get current time in the philippines using php?

Tags: php, time

how to get the exact time(well not that exact) in philippines which is GMT + 08:00 or atleast my exact time in desktop?
the code below gives me correct date but wrong time

dont bother about the +5minute thing im just tryin to test something

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php


$todays_date = date("y-m-d h:i:sa");
$today = strtotime($todays_date);
echo "<br>";echo "<br>";
echo "Current time ";
echo "<br>";


echo date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", $today);

$todays_date = date("y-m-d h:i:sa");
$today = strtotime($todays_date);
echo "<br>";echo "<br>";
echo "Current time + 5minutes";
echo "<br>";
$today1=strtotime("+5 minutes");

echo date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", $today1);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked at `date_default_timezone_set()`?  Googled it at all first?

Comment: dont know about that function thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php file

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
```

just add this single code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
$todays_date = date("y-m-d h:i:sa");
$today = strtotime($todays_date);
echo "<br>";echo "<br>";
echo "Current time ";
echo "<br>";


echo date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", $today);

$todays_date = date("y-m-d h:i:sa");
$today = strtotime($todays_date);
echo "<br>";echo "<br>";
echo "Current time + 5minutes";
echo "<br>";
$today1=strtotime("+5 minutes");

echo date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", $today1);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
```

For Supported time zone, check [PHP supported timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)